# How to show interstitial ads after certain button clicks ? (Click Counter)

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

I'm new to android development, and I was trying to show the interstitial ads after 5 button clicks, below is my code which is not working, kindly someone guide me how to solve this.

```js
int counter = 0;

...



  FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
  FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

  Button play_video = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.play_video);
  play_video.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    
   @Override
      
   public void onClick(View v) {
    if (counter == 5) {
     if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
      mInterstitialAd.show();
      counter = 0;
     } else {
      counter++;
      stream(vidData);
      getDialog().dismiss();

     }

     if (!mInterstitialAd.isLoading() && !mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
      AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
      mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
     }
    }
   }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying on the variable, use [shared preference](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) to store the count. and then do something like

```
// update the value in the shared preference here

if (count % 5 == 0)  //then show your advert
```

I think this will work.

Comment: not working .. app is crash closing. can you show me some examples in the above code? iam new into coding